# extracting data using mapstatetoprops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have this component where I need some data from my Redux store.
However, I see it has been passed some other required data in a bit different way. My concern is as how to use mapStateToProps in this case and get the data.

Here is the component where I need to extract data from redux store:

```
const NavBarScore = withStyles(navBarScoreStyles)(
  ({ classes, matchDetails }) => {
    // some opeartions on matchDetails
    return (
      <span className={classes.middleScoreContainer}>
        <span className={classes.teamName}>{scoreData.homeTeamName}</span>
        <span className={classes.teamName}>{scoreData.awayTeamName} </span>
      </span>
    );
  }
);
```

I see that in one of the component there is something like this, where CricketFantasy is in one of the rooteReducer:

```
const NavBarScore = connect(({ cricketFantasy: { matchDetails } }) => ({
  matchDetails
}))(NavScore);
```

I tried doing similar thing in another component and accessing it but it does not show any data.
My concern is how to simply get data from redux in this component using mapstatetoprops.

Answer (score 0):

Create a container component for NavScore say NavScoreContainer which will dispatch events to redux and fetches data and maps state to props.

For example:-

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return ({
        scores: state.scores
    })
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    fetchScores: () => {
        dispatch(fetchScores());
    }
})

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(NavScore)
```

Here **scores** will be passed as a prop to the component and can be accessed as this.props.scores.

Comment: Well .This doesn't answer the question .I would like to see what container component you are talking about .As i understand the first component in code is some hoc .

Comment: connect and withStyles are both HOC, wrapping another component would be too redundant.

Answer (score 0):

declare your component like this:

```
const NavBarScore = ({ classes, matchDetails }) => {
    // some opeartions on matchDetails
    return (
      <span className={classes.middleScoreContainer}>
        <span className={classes.teamName}>{scoreData.homeTeamName}</span>
        <span className={classes.teamName}>{scoreData.awayTeamName} </span>
      </span>
    )
  }
```

with the declaration of your NavBarScore component, just export it this way:

```
export default withStyles(navBarScoreStyles)(connect(({ cricketFantasy: { matchDetails } }) => ({ matchDetails: cricketFantasyMatchDetails }))(NavBarScore))
```

When you import it, it will get the data you need or assign it to a new variable if you only need it in the same file.

```
const NavBarScoreWithData = withStyles(navBarScoreStyles)(connect(({ cricketFantasy: { matchDetails } }) => ({ matchDetails: cricketFantasyMatchDetails }))(NavBarScore))
```

this is assuming that you have `cricketFantasy.matchDetails` in your global state, else you can review and test it with `connect(state => state)`